# How To Call a Common function to Every (Twig) Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Hi I have a common function to get a Client Name dynamicaly. Now I want to call that function to every view (Twig). I am following it like this:

```
//My controler
public function getSchoolNameAction(){
        $session = new Session();
        $dm = $this->getDocumentManager();
        $commonFunction = new CommonFunctions();
        return $schoolName= $commonFunction->schoolName($dm,$session);

}

//My View (search.html.twig)
{% render controller('EduAccountBundle:Ledger:getSchoolName') %}
But its showing an error that :
he controller must return a response (null given). I need to make it for every view. Please guide me how to fix this
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't define a controller as a service, controllers should be used only to take a request and to produce a response (you're just returning a value, that isn't acceptable for Symfony logic)

Unless you want to return a rendered template (or produce a valid response, such like a json response) to put where you're calling the common action (you could do that of course), I will recommend to write a [custom twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Without Creating twig extension it not possible?

Comment: @user3458514 as I told you, you need to return a valid response. in this case I would suggest a template already rendered or a json response. What you can't return is a scalar value or something else that's not a valid Response.

Comment: OK DonCallisto. let me try: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Please see this:
http://www.dinduks.com/symfony-2-render-helper-for-calling-an-action-from-a-view/

I am following this. but stuck

Comment: http://www.dinduks.com/symfony-2-render-helper-for-calling-an-action-from-a-view/